# How to set sidebar menu on bootstrap admin?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [this bootstrap theme](http://www.ampleadmin.wrappixel.com/ampleadmin-html/ampleadmin-rtl/index.html).

What should I change in order to leave the sidebar (side menu) open by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in style.css

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar,
  .sidebar .sidebar-head {
    width: 240px;
  }

  .sidebar .hide-menu {
    display:inline;
  }

  .sidebar .nav-second-level li a {
    padding-right: 30px;
  }
 }
```